# Javascript pass function in object value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, Is it possible to pass a function in key's value?

Here is what I have tried without success : (

```
const myArray = [

 {
        buttonSelector: '.edit_button',
        buttonFunc: '() => console.log('test'),
 }
]
```

To run the function:

```
myArray.forEach(element => {
element.buttonFunc
}) // should console.log('test')
```

Comment: just don't use single quotes around the function?

Comment: `element.buttonFunc()` and remove the single quote of course

Comment: Not only possible but exceedingly common.

Comment: You have a typo; there's an extra quote after `buttonFunc:`... If you wanted to call the function without using the `()`, that's possible too, but you need to change how you define that property.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want `buttonFunc` to be a function, then do not enclose it in quotation marks, because that makes it a string and not a function:

> ```
> buttonFunc: '() => console.log("test")',
> ```

should be

```
buttonFunc: () => console.log('test'),
```

Then you can execute it like so:

```
myArray.forEach(element => {
    element.buttonFunc();
});
// should console.log('test')
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not executing `element.buttonFunc`. Instead, for each element the following function will be called:

```
function() {
    element.buttonFunc;
}
```

Hence, it's not being executed.

To get your `forEach` working, try the following:

```
myArray.forEach(element => element.buttonFunc())
```